# RTMP authentication not working using libav

Tags: authentication, rtmp, wowza, libavcodec, libav

I am trying to implement RTSP to RTMP restreamer using libav. The "ffmpeg" command works OK:

```
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://localhost:8884/live" -vcodec copy -f rtsp "rtmp://user:password@localhost:1935/live/stream"
```

But I am getting RTMP authentication errors when I do it using libav. These are the ways I tried:

```
avformat_alloc_output_context2(&m_outformat, NULL, "rtsp", "rtmp://user:password@localhost:1935/live/stream");
avformat_alloc_output_context2(&m_outformat, NULL, "rtsp", "rtmp://localhost:1935/live/stream?user&password");
avformat_alloc_output_context2(&m_outformat, NULL, "rtsp", "rtmp://localhost:1935/live?user&password/stream");
avformat_alloc_output_context2(&m_outformat, NULL, "rtsp", "rtmp://localhost:1935/live/stream?username=user&password=password");
avformat_alloc_output_context2(&m_outformat, NULL, "rtsp", "rtmp://localhost:1935/live?username=user&password=password/stream");
avformat_alloc_output_context2(&m_outformat, NULL, "rtsp", "rtsp://user:password@localhost:1935/live/stream")
```

Can someone please let me know  how I can enable RTMP authentication.

As you could see above we are using "rtsp" as "format_name" and the URL starts with "rtmp://". This is because when we kept "rtsp" in both, "m_outformat->pb" is coming as NULL and subsequent call to "avio_open" is giving error.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to stream in RTMP, your format_name should be "flv" instead of "rtsp". The authentication scheme in an RTMP stream is different from an RTSP stream, and you would need to specify that.

The following ffmpeg command should work with an RTMP authentication scheme (tested on Windows platform):

```
ffmpeg -re -i "rtsp://localhost:8884/live/myStream"  -c:v copy -c:a copy -f flv "rtmp://localhost/live/myStream flashver=FMLE/3.0\20(compatible;\20FMSc/1.0) live=true pubUser=user pubPasswd=password"
```

If you are using a Linux platform, test with the following:

```
avformat_alloc_output_context2(&m_outformat, NULL, "flv", "rtmp://user:password@localhost:1935/live/stream");
```